# how to display the mobile no in mobile no label searching by employee id in html using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to display the mobile number in mobileNo label but when I enter the employee id for search this code displays no result.

I want to display data using the while loop in my html form

search.php

```html
<?php
        
        $output = NULL;
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db") or die ("Error in connection");
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
         {
         $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['search']));
         $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id = '$search'");
         if($resultSet->num_rows > 0)
             {
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($resultSet))
                {
             $mobileNo = $rows['emp_mob_no'];
             $output = "Mobile no: $mobileNo";
             }
          }
             {
          $output = "No result";
          }
        }
        ?>
```

---

display.php

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <label for="employeeId">Employee Id</label>
       <input type="text" name="employeeId" placeholder="Employee Id" />
       <input type="submit" value="search" name="search"/> 
       </li>
      <li>
        <label for="mobileNo">Mobile No.</label>
        <?php echo $output;?>
      </li>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you missed `else`

Comment: change below two line.


$employeeId = $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['employeeId']));
         $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id = '$employeeId'")

Comment: after enter else same thing is happening

Comment: Try my below answer @sri

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** you missed `else` That's why **$output** variable alwasy overwrite by No result .

**2nd :** `$search = $mysqli->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['search']));` this line wrong isset will return boolean value your escaping for boolean value .

**3rd :** Try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injection .

PHP:

```
<?php

        $output = NULL;
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db") or die ("Error in connection");
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
         {
            $search=$_POST['search'];

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id = ?");

            $stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['search']);

            $stmt->execute();

            $get_result = $stmt->get_result();

            if($get_result->num_rows > 0)
             {
               while($rows = $get_result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                   $mobileNo = $rows['emp_mob_no'];
                   $output = "Mobile no: $mobileNo";
                }

             }else //here else missed .
             {
                $output = "No result";
             }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$output = NULL;
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db") or die ("Error in connection");
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id = '$search'");
    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet))
        {
            $mobileNo = $rows['emp_mob_no'];
            $output = "Mobile no: $mobileNo";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = "No result";
    }
}

?>
```